# I fail to put fillOpacity and strokeOpacity to work in the Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps

I use the Google API to plot markers and a polygon. This works well, but I can't seem to get the polygon's fillOpacity and strokeOpacity working. It works when it is set to 0 or 1, which makes me believe that there is some kind of parsing error.
(I left the details out of the code below and just replaced it with example)

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
var locations = [
  ['EXAMPLETEXT, EXAMPLECOORDINATE1, EXAMPLECOORDINATE2, 1],
];

var limburgcoordinaten = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(EXAMPLECOORDINATE1, EXAMPLECOORDINATE2),
    new google.maps.LatLng(EXAMPLECOORDINATE1, EXAMPLECOORDINATE2),
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 8,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(EXAMPLECOORDINATE1, EXAMPLECOORDINATE2),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});


var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));

var limburg = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: limburgcoordinaten,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.7,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    fillOpacity: 0.3,
    map: map
});
}
```

I hope that i'm just looking over something very obvious!